# How to change color of image based on choice of color palette

Tags: javascript

I have an image that I'm trying to change the color of, I have a `<ul>` of colors, all displayed in small squares. I want to modify the color of my image based on which box the user clicks.

```
  <li swatch="3FB8AF"></li>
  <li swatch="7FC7AF"></li>
  <li swatch="DAD8A7"></li>
  <li swatch="FF9E9D"></li>
  <li swatch="FF3D7F"></li>
```

Ex. If someone clicks, `<li swatch="7BE0D0"></li>`, the image should change to that color.

Comment: What do you mean by *modify the color of my image* ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you mean by color if image. Here is example of changing color div

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="colors">
<li swatch="#3FB8AF"></li>
<li swatch="#7FC7AF"></li>
<li swatch="#DAD8A7"></li>
<li swatch="#FF9E9D"></li>
<li swatch="#FF3D7F"></li>
</ul>
<div style="height:500px;width:500px;font-size:50px" id="mainElm">Elment whose color will change</div>

<script>
var colors = document.querySelectorAll('ul#colors > li');
for(let color of colors){
    color.style.backgroundColor = color.getAttribute("swatch");
    color.style.height = "50px";
    color.style.width = "50px";
    color.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById('mainElm').style.backgroundColor = color.getAttribute('swatch');
    }
}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by modifying the colour of an image. However here's an example that adds background colour to each swatch square, a click listener to their container, and a function that adds color to another element when a swatch square is clicked. It will give you some idea about the steps needed when you come to code this yourself.

1) You should use data attributes in your HTML. `data-color="3FB8AF"` instead of `swatch="3FB8AF"` to ensure your HTML is valid.

2) I'm using ["event delegation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). Instead of adding a listener to each color element you can add one listener to the containing element which captures the events as they bubble up the DOM from its children.

Hope this helps.

```js
// Cache the swatch element (the `ul`), and add
// an event listener to it. This calls `handleClick`
// when it is clicked or any of its child elements are clicked
const swatch = document.querySelector('ul');
swatch.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Cache the color squares in the swatch, and the "image" element
const colorSquares = document.querySelectorAll('li');
const img = document.querySelector('.image');

// Destructures the dataset from the element that
// was clicked and calls `setColor`, passing in the
// element to which we need to apply the color
function handleClick(e) {
  const { dataset: { color } } = e.target;
  setColor(img, color);
}

// Accepts an element and a color - sets
// the background color of the element.
// Note: because the data-color attribute doesn't
// contain a preceding hash we have to add it here 
function setColor(el, color) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = `#${color}`;  
}

// Iterates over the color squares and set each
// of their background color to the hex color in the
// dataset
[...colorSquares].forEach(colorSquare => {
  const { dataset: { color } } = colorSquare;
  setColor(colorSquare, color);
});
```

```css
ul { padding-left: 0; display: flex; flex-direction: row; list-style-type: none; }
li { height: 20px; width: 20px; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.image { text-align: center; border: 1px solid #676767; height: 50px; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-color="3FB8AF"></li>
  <li data-color="7FC7AF"></li>
  <li data-color="DAD8A7"></li>
  <li data-color="FF9E9D"></li>
  <li data-color="FF3D7F"></li>
</ul>

<div class="image">IMAGE</div>
```

Comment: I apologize for my unclear explanation. I’m still learning web development so this is a process for me. Basically, I have an image with 4 gray trapezoids on it. They aren’t connected, and the rest of the image is transparent, so if I used background-color, the trapezoids would remain gray, and the rest of the image would change colors. However, I want to be able to change the color of my trapezoids based on which color a user clicks, which will be preset under the image.